# Array declaration of size determined in running time java

Tags: java, arrays

```
-some code here-
n = smth(for example 5)
Team[] team = new Team[n]
```

can I write array like this, i.e. Can java determine size of array and make that many array of elements in run time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. So some code i am assuming here is like:

```
int n=100;
Team[] team = new Team[n];
```

This is valid in java. So you could access

```
System.out.println(team[50]);//which will print null
team[50] = new Team();//you set team here
System.out.println(team[50]);//which will print team now
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the size of array at runtime : ");
int n = sc.nextInt();
Team[] team = new Team[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could for instance this code :

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int n=5;
    String[] team = new String[n];
    System.out.println(team.length);
}
```

will print 5 in the out put, and this is exactly what you need.

Ideone online version [here](http://ideone.com/hDlh0o).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this code is legal and you can create arrays of size calculated at runtime.

The question is "why you just did not try this?" it takes several seconds comparing to several minutes that takes registration on SO and asking this question.

Comment: It's an interesting point you bring up. "Why didn't you just try it." Considering the OP is new to programming, for one that comes with insecurities.

Comment: @mattias, not all questions should be asked at public forum. Sometimes it is better to discover the question you have yourself. This is what I mean.